# How do I create a VB 6 application that has no hidden "framework" windows, like ThunderRT6Main?

Tags: vb6

I have a security requirement for my legacy vb6 application to not create any hidden windows such as ThunderRT6Main, which is a hidden window created for every vb aplication made.

I have tried creating activex dll's etc, and modifying the PE header to run as a true console exe but they all produce these hidden vb windows.

I understand these hidden windows are used for event processing but my exe has no GUI and is not event driven in any way.

Comment: I don't understand how it can be a security requirement, but does the difficulty of this task not suggest that you're using the wrong tool for the job? Why is VB6 a requirement?

Comment: This is a fully matured legacy vb6 app, which i dont want to consider porting, so have to stick with vb6 as far as I can see.

Comment: Oh, and thanks guys for getting back so quick :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as far as I know. Every VB 6 application will have a hidden, top-level window that the framework uses internally to receive notifications and other events from the system, as well as oversee all of the other windows in your application.

Even if you don't create any other forms, this top-level window will still be created, and there's nothing you can do to prevent it.

As others have mentioned, the best option is probably to create this application using a different programming language/GUI framework. The simplicity and ease-of-use of VB comes with costs.

Comment: ok, that sucks :(. Have spent quite a bit of time googling about it. Maybe if the classname/caption of the hidden window(s) could be changed at runtime, that might be plausible

Comment: @Simon It would certainly be *theoretically* possible to change the class name of the window, but I have no idea whether that would break things for VB 6. I imagine that it probably would. Why in the world does this matter? What is this "security" problem you're trying to solve, and why is it so trivial that is cares only about the class name or caption of a window?

Comment: I have a controlled environment, were this program must not be circumvented by malicious users. I run it with other 'stealth' measures so This hidden window is the only visible part of the program eg. were a malicious user can send a SC_CLOSE or kill message and bypass the security. I am trying to avoid porting the app as it will take many weeks/months to port and then retest everything

Comment: The main security objective is that the program is running completly invisible as there will be users with significant interests to try to hack/disable it.

Comment: @Simon Sorry, your existing "controlled environment" is trivially beatable. All you have to do is terminate the process, which doesn't require there to be any windows at all. You need to use something like Group Policy to lock down your machines and prevent users from closing stuff they don't have permissions to close.

Comment: I said that te only visible portion of the program is the window, the process is not visible

Comment: You can subclass `ThunderRT6Main` and prevent uncontrolled WM_SYSCOMMAND messages.

Comment: @Simon Processes are always visible to users with the appropriate permissions; the same with windows. However you're preventing users from closing the process is the same way that you should prevent the user from closing the window. And no, blocking `WM_SYSCOMMAND` messages won't work, you'll just prevent the machine from functioning. This is not a programming problem, it's a permissions problem, solvable using Group Policy.

Comment: Trust me, i am using methods to ensure the process is not visible. I am just seeking an answer to the question : Can the thunderrt6main and associated system windows not be spawned for a vb6 exe

Comment: I simply don't believe you. It would take a knowledgeable user under a half-hour to beat whatever system you've concocted. But if you're satisfied that it works, that's fine by me.

Comment: If you have the permissions to install something like this, you have the necessary permissions to remove it.

Comment: This is a 'Security through obscurity' approach http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity  . If they can detect the exe in any way, it makes it harder to hack it, whereas if it is exposed, there is opportunity to examine and exploit it

Comment: I don't get this. Surely, even if the ThunderRT6Main window was somehow removed, the console window could still be destroyed. Also, I would love to know how you think you can make your process unkillable. This sounds like yet another instance of the "Awesome Program" meme propogated by Raymond Chen, e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/07/21/10040699.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/15/10105142.aspx

Answer (score 0):

well i don't get it - its usual to have a hidden window - even when you're running as service you've to have hidden windows for example for processing asynchronous HTTP requests (as they are event driven).

what's the security reason anyway?

Comment: I have written non-gui/console apps in other languages that dont need to use events and they dont spawn hidden windows to send/receive window messages, so I would of thought this option would be possible with vb6 somehow?

Comment: VB6 isn't a "non-gui/console app" language.